# Can an android mobile client setup a new database on a Google Cloud account?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

More specifically I am looking to do this from an Android tablet, but I would like know if it's possible from any mobile device. My use case for multiple databases using Google Cloud is as follows...

A company downloads my app. The app asks for a login (with company name, admin username, and password) or allows the user to create a new account. When they choose to setup a new account (this is where I need help) and a new database is created in Google Cloud. Is this currently possible?

This is different from most apps, because most apps only need one database. I plan to have multiple databases because each company will have private data that doesn't need to be accessed by other companies. It should make queries much more efficient within each company, but any updates I apply to each database will be a little tedious. Regardless, I plan to go this route. Are there any better solutions to releasing an app to different companies (using separate databases)?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Cloud Endpoints for general mobile to AppEngine connectivity (you probably knew that).  Use Multitenancy, als known as Namespaces, to isolate the data belonging to each company.  Don't worry about separate databases, Datastore is one huge global database anyway that AppEngine partitions into bits for different accounts.

Comment: Interesting. I originally thought I'd use a MySQl database but yeah the Datastore looks a lot more scalable. Is using Google Messaging and JDA MySQLite locally the best way to keep data persistent across all devices of the company? Or is there a better way?